# How to delete three-letter words from text file

Tags: python

I want to open a text file that contains a word on each line, and save the contents to a new file, omitting any line whose word is three letters or less.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
linelist = f.readlines()

f.close

# Re-open file here
f2 = open('text4.txt', 'w')
for line in linelist:
    s = len(line)
    if s < 3 :
    #if len(line)<3:
        line = line.replace(s , 'new')
        f2.write(line)        
        f2.close()
        #print('yes')
        #print(line)
```

`test.txt` looks like:

```
winter
sat
written
wild
instrument
kept
glass
grass
cow
```

Expected result:

```
winter
written
wild
instrument
kept
glass
grass
```

Comment: I tried to replace all two letters words in file to the word "new"

Comment: your `line` will have `\n` so you want to do `line.strip()` first before you check for length.

Comment: but it work with print(line)

Comment: Also, do you want to close the file as soon as you find the first line with len 2 or lesser?

Comment: print(line) will convert `\n` to new line instead try `print (repr(line))` you will see the `\n` in it

Comment: I want. to save the text file into new text file and close

Comment: note that `\n` will count as len=1. Also, you are checking for len of a line. If the words are `independent formula`, then these two words will have a longer length. What are you trying to really check?

Comment: Also, `line.replace(s , 'new')` won't work. The `line` itself does not have a number. It has words. You are trying to replace the number with `new`. Check your code for logic.

Comment: you are right . but how to do it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a file with a few lines. There are lines that have only two words. You want to remove those lines and instead replace it with `new`. If the line has more than two words, say `i am good`, you want to keep that word. However, if the line has `hello world`, you want to remove it? Correct?

Comment: I have a long list of words many of them are two and three letters I don't want them I want just four letters and more to be saved. into another file

Comment: Oh. two letter words like `to`, `is`, `as`, `an`, `it`, `if`, ... and three letter words like `and`, `but`, `how`, ...  You want to remove them. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you share the sample file so i know what you have as an input file?

Comment: exactly that what I want

Comment: test file like : able  boy house words book be find

Comment: share the test file data in your question section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code to remove all words that are less than or equal to 3 letters.

```
with open('xyz.txt', 'r') as f1, open('abc.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        if len(line) > 4: f2.write(line)
```

The input is your source data. The output in the new file is as shown below. All other data was removed.

```
winter
written
wild
instrument
kept
glass
grass
edge
sign
visit
past
soft
bright
weather
month
million
bear
finish
happy
hope
flower
clothe
strange
gone
jump
baby
eight
village
meet
root
raise
solve
metal
whether
```